# passing multidimensional arrays to functions

Tags: c++, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, pass-by-reference

[the 7 functions i need to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T0xo.jpg)

this file is using arrays to retrieve data from an input file and display the data onto an output file. I'm having trouble with the void input data function. The call function inputdata(inputFile,  nonNumerical, numeric1); is getting an error saying error: cannot convert 'int (*)[2]' to 'double (*)[2]' for argument '3' to 'void inputdata(std::ifstream&, std::string(*)[9], double(*)[2])'

```
#include <fstream>
  #include <string>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cmath>
 using namespace std;


 const int courseSize = 3;
 const int examSize = 6;
 const int studsize =3;
 const int strSize =9;
 const int numSize = 2;
 void inputdata(ifstream &, string  [][strSize],double [][numSize]);
 int main()
 {


int n=0, x, y;
int strLength =0;
double scoreTotal =0;
char lettergrade;

string header, name, address, phone, social, course, studentID;
const int letterGrade_A = 90;
const int letterGrade_B = 80;
const int letterGrade_C = 70;
const int letterGrade_D = 60;

int age, yearsAtTXST, numstudents;
double testscore;
double numGrade = 0;
const int minStrLength = 1;
const int maxStrLength = 100;
const int minint = 1;
const int maxint = 100;
const int minCourse = 1;
const int maxCourse = 3;
const int minTest = 1;
const int maxTest = 5;
const double test1 = 0.10;
const double test2 = 0.15;
const double test3 =0.15;
const double test4 = 0.20;
const double final_test = 0.40;
const double maxGrade = 100.0, minGrade = 1.0;

//    initialize arrays
string nonNumerical[studsize][strSize];
int numeric1[studsize][numSize];
double numeric2[studsize][courseSize][examSize];
char lettergrades[studsize][courseSize];

cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

// opening files
ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open("Project5_A04314548_Input.txt");
ofstream fout;
fout.open  ("Project5_A04314548_Output.txt");

if( !( inputFile && fout))
{
    cout << "Error opening file.\n";
 }


  cout << " Enter a number of students: ";
 cin >> numstudents;

  while( !(numstudents ==3))
 {
    cout << " error number of students must be 3. Enter again: ";
    cin >> numstudents;
 }

 inputdata(inputFile,  nonNumerical, numeric1);

 // take in string data from input file
 for(int x =0; x< studsize; x++)
 {
    for(int y=0; y < strSize; y++)
    {
       if(y >= strSize)
       break;

       getline(inputFile, nonNumerical[x][y]);
       strLength = nonNumerical[x][y].length();
       if(strLength < minStrLength || strLength > maxStrLength)
        {
        fout << " The given string for nonNumerical [" << x << "][" << y <<  
"] is not within the proper range of 1-100 characters." << endl;
        fout << " Please fix the issue and rerun the program for a correct    
 output." << endl << endl;
        continue;
        }
    }
  }

  //above put into input data function

  // take in data from input file
  for(int x=0; x<studsize;x++)
  {
     for(int y=0; y < numSize; y++)
     {
         if(y>=numSize)
            break;

        inputFile >> numeric1[x][y];
        if( numeric1[x][y] < minint || numeric1[x][y] > maxint)
        {
        fout << "The given integer for numerical1[" << x << "][" << y <<    
  "]is not within the proper range of 1-100." << endl;
        fout << " please fix the problem and rerun the program for a correct     
 output." << endl << endl;
        break;
        }

     }
    }

   // above put into data function

    // take in double data from input file
  for( int x1=0; x1<studsize; x1++)
  {
    for(int x2=0; x2 < courseSize; x2++)
    {
        for(int x3=0; x3<(examSize-1);x3++)
        {
            if(x3 >=(examSize-1))
                break;
            inputFile >> numeric2[x1][x2][x3];
            if( numeric2[x1][x2][x3] < minGrade || numeric2[x1][x2][x3] >   
  maxGrade)
            {
                cout << "The given value fro numeric2[" << x1 << "][" << x2 
  << "][" << x3 << "] is not within the proper range of 1-100" << endl
                << "Please fix the issue and rerun the program for a correct   
  output." << endl;
                break;
            }

            else if( x3 == 0)
                scoreTotal += (numeric2[x1][x2][x3]* test1);
            else if( x3== 1)
                scoreTotal += (numeric2[x1][x2][x3]* test2);
            else if( x3 == 2)
                scoreTotal += (numeric2[x1][x2][x3]* test3);
            else if( x3 == 3)
                scoreTotal += (numeric2[x1][x2][x3]* test4);
            else
                scoreTotal += (numeric2[x1][x2][x3]* final_test);
            }

            numeric2[x1][x2][5] = scoreTotal; // final numeric grade
            scoreTotal = 0;

            if(x2 >=courseSize)
                break;
            if((numeric2[x1][x2][5] > maxGrade) || (numeric2[x1][x2][5] < 
  minGrade) )
            {
                cout << "Error in calculating grade. Please fix the issue     
   then rerun the program. ignore broken program!";
                cout << endl << endl;
                continue;

            }

            else if(numeric2[x1][x2][5] >= letterGrade_A)
                lettergrades[x1][x2] = 'A';
            else if(numeric2[x1][x2][5] >= letterGrade_B)
                lettergrades[x1][x2] = 'B';
            else if(numeric2[x1][x2][5] >= letterGrade_C)
                lettergrades[x1][x2] = 'C';
            else if(numeric2[x1][x2][5] >= letterGrade_D)
                lettergrades[x1][x2] = 'D';
            else
                lettergrades[x1][x2] = 'F';

    }
   }

    for(int a1=0; a1< studsize; a1++)
    {   fout << nonNumerical[a1][0]<< endl;
        fout << right << setw(35) << "Name of Student:\t";
        fout << nonNumerical[a1][1] << endl;
        fout << right << setw(35) << "Student ID:\t";
        fout << nonNumerical[a1][2]<< endl;
        fout << right << setw(35) << "Address:\t" ;
        fout << nonNumerical[a1][3] << endl;
        fout << right << setw(35) << "Telephone Number:\t";
        fout <<  nonNumerical[a1][4] << endl;
        fout << right << setw(35) << "Student Soc. Security:\t";
        fout << nonNumerical[a1][5] << endl;
        fout << right << setw(35) << "Age:\t";
        fout << numeric1[a1][0] << endl;
        fout << right << setw(35) << "Number of years at Texas State:\t";
        fout << numeric1 [a1][1] << endl << endl;




    for(int b1=0; b1 <courseSize; b1++)
    {
        fout << right << setw(35) << "Course number:\t";
            fout << nonNumerical[a1][(b1+6)] << endl;

        for(int c1= 0; c1 <(examSize-1); c1++)
        {
        fout << right << setw(32) << "Exam #" << (a1 +1) << ":\t";
            fout << numeric2[a1][b1][c1] << endl;
        }

        fout << right << setw(35) << "Numerical grade:\t";
        fout << numeric2[a1][b1][5] << endl;
        fout << right << setw(35) << "Letter grade:\t";
        fout << lettergrades[a1][b1] << endl;

        if( numeric2[a1][b1][5] < 70)
        {
        fout << right << setw(14) << " Warning Note: Your grade is too low 
 and needs improvements!" << endl << endl;
        }
        else if ( numeric2[a1][b1][5] >= 95)
        {
        fout << right << setw(14) << " Appreciation Note: Congratulations,      
 Your performance is Excellent!" << endl << endl;
        }
        else
        fout << endl;



    }
    fout << endl;
}


 inputFile.close();
 fout.close();

return 0;
}




 void inputdata(ifstream & inputFile, string   array1[][strSize],double    
 array2[]    
[numSize])
{
  for(int x =0; x< studsize; x++)
  {
    for(int y=0; y < strSize; y++)
    {
       if(y >= strSize)
       break;

       getline(inputFile,  array1[x][y]);
    }
  }


 for(int a1=0; a1<studsize;a1++)
 {
     for(int a2=0; a2 < numSize; a2++)
     {
         if(a2>=numSize)
            break;

        inputFile >> array2[a1][a2];
    }
 }


}
```

Comment: If the issue is passing multidimension arrays, why did you need to write a full blown program to learn how to do this?  Just create a simple dummy function, and attempt to call it.  If you can't figure it out with a simple function, then ask.  Just posting your entire project code doesn't help...

Comment: Example: http://ideone.com/qkMUDr  That is what you start with, or at least have a simple project with a working example.  Then you take the working example and incorporate it into the larger program.  Now, do you see the difference between what works (the code at the link), and what you're doing?  Then you can take the simple example and change it to attempt to do what you're trying to do.  You keep working with the simple example until you get a clean compile.  *Then* you make those changes to the larger program -- that is how any developer approaches issues like this.  Start simple, work up

Comment: thank you i used this technique to finish my project but it has an error building and running the program now. It says the name of the file has stopped working windows is looking for a solution. any ideas on what i should look for?